# Выполняется только 2 первые функции бота телеграм

Tags: python, telebot, pyowm

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет\n' + 
        'Данный бот создан для того что бы увидеть погоду\n' 
        + 'напиши названия любого города на русском языке.')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def temp(message):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']

    answer = 'В городе '+ message.text + ' сейчас ' + w.detailed_status + '\n'
    answer += 'Температура сейчас в районе ' + str(temp) + '\n'

    if temp < 10:
        answer += 'Сейчас холодно! Советую надеть куртку, или остаться дома!'
    elif temp < 14:
        answer += 'Сейчас прохладно, оденься теплее!'
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += 'Сейчас Не так уж и холодно. Для осени достаточно тепло!'
    elif temp > 20:
        answer += 'Сейчас очень жарко! Езжай на пляж!'
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer,)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['button'])
def create_button(message):
    try:
        markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1=types.KeyboardButton('Информация')
        markup.add(item1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите кнопку', reply_markup=markup)
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что то пошло не так...')

def info(message):
    if (message.text=='Информация'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Инфа о боте', reply_markup=markup)


bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

При вводе команды "button" выбивает с ошибкой "pyowm.commons.exceptions.NotFoundError: Unable to find the resource"

Answer (score 0):

Делай так

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет\n' + 
        'Данный бот создан для того что бы увидеть погоду\n' 
        + 'напиши названия любого города на русском языке.')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['button'])
def create_button(message):
    try:
        markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1=types.KeyboardButton('Информация')
        markup.add(item1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите кнопку', reply_markup=markup)
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что то пошло не так...')

def info(message):
    if (message.text=='Информация'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Инфа о боте', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def temp(message):
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']

    answer = 'В городе '+ message.text + ' сейчас ' + w.detailed_status + '\n'
    answer += 'Температура сейчас в районе ' + str(temp) + '\n'

    if temp < 10:
        answer += 'Сейчас холодно! Советую надеть куртку, или остаться дома!'
    elif temp < 14:
        answer += 'Сейчас прохладно, оденься теплее!'
    elif temp < 20:
        answer += 'Сейчас Не так уж и холодно. Для осени достаточно тепло!'
    elif temp > 20:
        answer += 'Сейчас очень жарко! Езжай на пляж!'
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer,)


bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Comment: Теперь после нажатия на кнопку инфа, текст не появляется, видимо функция с погодой проверяет слово инфа а не функция инфо. Выбивает с ошибкой такой же pyowm. и так далее